# Are event keys same on windows and mac?

Tags: javascript

If I want to check if `enter` is pressed, I will do something like:

```
addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') alert('You pressed enter!');
});
```

So, will that same code work on a Mac, will it register mac's `return` as `enter`?

Comment: Yes they are same,Possible duplicate of [How to detect pressing Enter on keyboard using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery)

Comment: 13 is equal for enter key, you can try `e.key === 13` which should return true on every where mac, windows etc

Comment: [javascript - Replacement for deprecated `keypress` DOM event - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882144/replacement-for-deprecated-keypress-dom-event)

Comment: As @AyazShah stated, use the code - this will be more reliable.

Comment: @Justcode This is not a jQuery question but a pure javascript question

Comment: @Justcode This is pure javascript, how did jquery come into this? And I still don't have a definite answer. So `e.key` will be equal to `Enter` on a mac?

Comment: @jukenduit I know this is javascript, the question is about the key code, instead of the enter you can use 13 that's it, its not about javascript or jquery its about keycode.

Comment: @Justcode No, the Q is about key not keycode. I can use e.keycode 13 but not e.key 13.

Comment: @jukenduit there are 2 questions included, both are answered in my comment. please check

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in the [MDN table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values#whitespace_keys) the answer is "Yes", they are the same.