# What code Can I use instead of "keypress" and "even.key"

Tags: javascript, keypress

VS code crosses out event.key. I think it's deprecated. I want the code below to run when I press enter. What should I do
VS code crosses out event.key. I think it's deprecated. I want the code below to run when I press enter. What should I do

```
  //js code    
  document.querySelector("#addNewTaskBtn").addEventListener("click",newTask);    
  document.querySelector("#addNewTaskBtn").addEventListener("keypress",()=>{    
     // Problem is here
    if(event.key=="Enter"){
     //vs code crosses out event.key. I think it's deprecated. I want the code below to 
     //run  whenI press enter. What should I do
         document.getElementById("addNewTaskBtn");
          }
    });
```

Comment: It should be `"keypress", (event) ` instead of `"keypress", () `

Answer (score 1):

[Replacement for deprecated `keypress` DOM event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882144/replacement-for-deprecated-keypress-dom-event)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code

`Keydown` is likely your better choice instead of `keypress`, and `KeyboardEvent.code` is likely your better choice instead of `event.key`.

Comment: `event.code` and `event.key` are both equally valid as they do different things (`event.key` depends on the keyboard layout while `event.code` doesn't).

Comment: Definitely had a brainfart, it's `event.keyCode` that's deprecated, you're right