# Angular driven forms how to disable the option write decimal numbers at number input

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a form in Angular which i want that the user will only submit a full number (not decimal) and he will not have the option to write .(dot) symbol in the form in order to write the decimal number. I want to block completely the option to write .(dot) at the form. 
Is it possible?

I tried the solution here :
[Proper way to restrict text input values (e.g. only numbers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435529/proper-way-to-restrict-text-input-values-e-g-only-numbers)
Using regex :

In component.ts add this function

```
_keyUp(event: any) {
    const pattern = /[0-9\+\-\ ]/;
    let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);

    if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
      // invalid character, prevent input
      event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

In your template use the following

```
<input(keyup)="_keyUp($event)">
```

But it did not work, the option to  write .(dot) at the form is still possible.

I want to block completely the option to write .(dot) at the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the character is already present at the time of the `keyup` event, and you can't *prevent* something that has already happened. Try the `keypress` event:

```
<input (keypress)="_keyUp($event)">
```

Answer (score 1):

@CDelaney is correct, but some additional thoughts: [This (found) stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/numeric-only?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) I would say does it better:

Component html:

```
<input (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" type="text">
```

and the TS file:

```
numberOnly(event): boolean {
const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
   if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
   return false;
}
  return true;
}
```

Why it's better?

1. No regex: as the saying goes, if you try to solve a problem with Regex, now you have two problems.
2. Keypress, it will be closer to what you want without having to replace strings
3. Better event names. If I had my druthers _namesOfAnything would never be a thing.