# Angular form input with only 2 decimals?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have an input like the following:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="number" [placeholder]="'Hours' | translate"
                formControlName="Work" (blur)="calculate()" />
</mat-form-field>
```

Right now, the input allows unlimited decimals. I would like to only allow 2 decimals on that input. It could be done with any of the following solutions:

- Restrict the input to 2 decimals, so that I can't insert more
- Allow unlimited decimals and round to 2 decimals when I click another component

> Is there any included feature in Angular for doing that? Otherwise,
>   how can I create that restriction/rounding?

Example of the second option:

1. The user enters the value 1,2582399512
2. When the input is unfocused, the value is rounded to 1,26

Comment: I’d use a directive on the input element. I find it weird that angular community haven't figure out a way of sharing common directives and services.

Comment: Can you give some example input / output. My guess is that you would allow the input 1234.5678, but then round to 1234.57?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to achieve @KurtHamilton

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58986023/need-angular-directive-digit-number-and-or-two-decimal-in-the-textbox/58991082#58991082

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this solution will round up but the "step" property can help your case:

```
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput type="number" [placeholder]="'Hours' | translate"
            formControlName="Work" (blur)="calculate()" step=".01"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

This will allow to enter more values but will give error if exceeded 2 decimal places. 
I hope it helps.