# enter number in text box should be in decimal with two digits

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am trying to put value in text box with two decimal digits 
example 
by default it take .00 on entering number

I am using Angular , Reactive form with form Control .

I am sharing my code  :

```
<input placeholder="00.00" (keypress)="convert($event)" formControlName='pendingDuesAmount' [(ngModel)]='pendingAmount'  type="text" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
```

**TS**

```
 pendingAmount : number = 0.00  

  convert(event): boolean {
      this.pendingAmount.toFixed(2)
  }
```

Comment: Well and what's the error ?

Comment: Anurag, NOT mix formControlName and [(ngModel)]. Programing is not a "totum revolutum", it's not put code and code and expect work it. Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58986023/need-angular-directive-digit-number-and-or-two-decimal-in-the-textbox?noredirect=1&lq=1,