# Get raw string value of an input form control with type number

Tags: angular

Is it possible to get the raw string value of an input with type number?

Example code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input
      type="number"
      [formControl]="control"
      (ngModelChange)="getStringValue(control)"
    />
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  control = this.fb.control('');
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  getStringValue(control: FormControl): void {
    console.log(control.value);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ztoivb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Assuming I can't change the template (it's a requirement by the client) and I want to get the number of decimals or check if this number contains a decimal separator, is this possible?

When I enter `100.00` or `100.` into the input field the property `control.value` contains `100`. I can't find any method like `getRawValue` to access the underlying string.

I know I can suggest to change the type of the `input` element to `text` but first I have to find out if there are other ways to solve this.

Comment: you can not use `type=number` and use some kind of mask. Some time ago I made one for input in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58986023/need-angular-directive-digit-number-and-or-two-decimal-in-the-textbox/58991082#58991082)

Comment: @Eliseo _"I know I can suggest to change the type of the input element to text but first I have to find out if there are other ways to solve this."_ I can solve it with type text. That's pretty easy. But is it also possible with type number?

Comment: can you try `control.valueAsNumber` ?  https://twitter.com/stackblitz/status/1362048512943398914

Comment: yes, is possible, simple pass the function the "htmlElement", for this you can use a template reference variable (see the answer)

Comment: @Eliseo I'm currently trying it. I think that's it

Comment: @halilcakar That doesn't work with an Angular FormControl but it probably works with the fix in the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can get the "HTMLElement", I like use a template reference variable,

```
<input #inputControl
      type="number"
      [formControl]="control"
      (ngModelChange)="getStringValue(inputControl)"
    />

  getStringValue(control: any): void {
    console.log(control.value);
  }
```

Comment: It works with `100.00` but it doesn't work with `100.`. When I enter `100.` it's still `100` without decimal separator.