# How to restrict the user from entering a value below certain value?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an html file with input field

<input type="text" allow-decimal="true" allow-negative="false"
ng-model="amount"

and i have a controller.js file with scope variables
$scope.amount=40000; and have one more scope variable $scope.minAmount= 2000;

So, what i want to do is I want to restrict the user from entering any value below 2000.
User should not be allowed to enter anything below the value 2000.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set attributes max and min for maximum and minimum values inside an input element in html itself

```
<input type="number" name="id" min="2000">
```

This will set the minimum value for input as 2000. Similarly you can set a maximum value using max attribute.

Comment: Is there any way to do it with type as text? i.e type="text" instead of type as number

Comment: That is not the right way to do things but nevertheless you can find the answer here. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435529/proper-way-to-restrict-text-input-values-e-g-only-numbers). If you find this helpful please accept the answer :)